# Find a value and return values from cells below

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, match, vlookup

I am trying to find a solution where I can find a value in the range and in return I have an array with cells underneath. There will be between 0-5 cells that I want to return and they always be the last one

Here is a simple example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FAoLD7udTVCL7qy5jdkPMufdjAnxdCwHkxZrswSJADo/edit?usp=sharing

[Example with expected solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ekVL.png)

I am almost there with a returned value but instead of an array I have just one cell. I have tried to rewrite the formula to use Array but failed.

Appreciate your help and/or feedback

Comment: This pattern reflects the real data which I can not publish. But the Color of Bananas is autoupdating every day with 0-5 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Banana", A:A, 0)+2, 1)&":"&
          ADDRESS(MATCH("Banana", A:A, 0)+4, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: I started playing with your solution and wondering if there is a possibility to limit the returned rows with some value/text. I will add in A9 a value **Carrot** and I want to return everything between Banana+1 and Carrot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUahK.png)

Comment: @dbd try: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Banana", A:A, 0)+2, 1)&":"&
          ADDRESS(MATCH("Carrot", A:A, 0)-1, 1))`